# Android Studio Application crashes on some devices at start

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have an app with Libgdx, where I use google play services and ads from appodeal and suddenly it crashes on some devices. On my phone (a Galaxy J5, API 22) it works just fine, but on another phone it doesn't launch. The phone with problems is Samsung SM-G3815 (Android 4.4.2, API 19)

```
07-29 19:05:48.758 10710-10710/com.NeverMind.MainClass.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.NeverMind.MainClass.android, PID: 10710
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.games.Games$GamesOptions
    at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.<init>(GameHelper.java:114)
    at com.NeverMind.DontFall.android.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is where it crashes in the AndroidLauncher:

```
gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
```

And this is where it crashes in GameHelper:

```
    GamesOptions mGamesApiOptions = GamesOptions.builder().build();
```

EDIT 1:
build gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
}
}

allprojects {
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"

version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = 'DontFall'
    gdxVersion = '1.6.4'
    roboVMVersion = '1.5.0'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
    ashleyVersion = '1.6.0'
    aiVersion = '1.5.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
}
}

project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0"
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
}
android {
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
}
}

project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
}
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: Where is your build.gradle app module code? How did you use google services?

Comment: @Rotwang My phone is Galaxy J5, api 22